# MVC generic repository common dataColumn

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, repository

I have a generic repository that I use for common things such as FetchAllData, GetbyID and so on... Anyway, I want to include a `Deactivate(T Entity)` method so that instead of deleting data I will just turn their status off so the user will not see the data, but I can see it whenever I need. Basically, something similar to:

```
public interface IGenericRepository<T> where T : class {
     ...somecode
}

public class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T> where T : class {
    public T GetbyID(int id) { ... }

    public void Deactivate(T entity) {
        entity.stat = 0; // I know that this stat is common in all tables. However,
                         // my problem is that I don't know how to make appear stat
                         // in IntelliSense.
    }
}
```

I know that this can be done, but I how do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a interface:

```
public interface IDeactivatable {
    int stats { get; set; }
}
```

Then your entities must derive from IDeactivatable.

Tip: You can add a generic type constraint too:

```
 [...] IGenericRepository<T> where T : class, IDeactivatable [...]
```

Comment: well I've done that but still not working. Can you be more specific please

Comment: Ok, thanks, now its working :) I'll appoint your answer as the correct answer whenever the time constraint dissapears

Comment: Lol, you post the same answer at the same time... damn ;) The funny thing is that you take the same interface name ;)